# How do I write up a new command to implement '\quad \text{} \quad'?

Tags: spacing

I would like to abbreviate `\quad \text{} \quad`. I tried `\newcommand{\wtext}{\quad \text{} \quad}` but the output proved me wrong. So I wonder how to properly achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to insert text into the `\text{}` or not?

Comment: Uh, in the preamble I do not want so.

Comment: you put the correct answer in the question so it is hard to give an answer. But why would you ever want that construct? It makes a 1 em space, an empty box, an inter-word space, then another 1 em space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in the parameter and access it as `#1`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\wtext}[1]{\quad \text{#1}\quad}

\begin{document}
$\quad \text{some text} \quad$

$\wtext{some text}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: you probably want to omit the space between `\text{#1} \quad`.  if the result is in one line, the resulting space will be larger than one em, and stretchable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Have corrected. I had left it in as I thought that as it was math mode that all spacing (exempt within `\text{}`) would be ignored.